# .htaccess redirect based on conditions and parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have tried many answers but none of them seems to work.

**WHAT I WANT?**

****1).** I want to redirect this(if it contains the parameters **from** & **to** and both of them are not empty):**

`https://arc.abc.com/mconvertar.php?from=gbp&to=jpy`

to

`https://arc.abc.com/gbpjpy/`

As you can see, we combined the values of from & to

****2).** And this(if it contains the parameter **x** along with **from** & **to**):**

`https://arc.abc.com/mconvertar.php?from=gbp&to=jpy&x=13`

to

`https://arc.abc.com/gbpjpy/x=13`

As you can see the 13 is the same as the above url.

****3).** And if **x** is empty then:**

`https://arc.abc.com/mconvertar.php?from=gbp&to=jpy&x=`

to

`https://arc.abc.com/gbpjpy/x=1`

As you can see we set the x value default to 1

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED?**

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)from=[^&\s]&to=[^&\s]&x=[0-9]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://arc.abc.com/gbpjpy/x=%3 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)x=($|&)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://arc.abc.com/gbpjpy/x=1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /mconvertar.php?from=$1&to=$2 [L]
```

**I really appreciate your help, Spent a lot of time**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `from` parameter is always 3 characters long. You may try these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one with x=<digit>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mconvertar\.php?from=(\w+)&to=([^\s&]+)&(x=\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2/%3? [R=302,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one with x=<empty>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mconvertar\.php?from=(\w+)&to=([^\s&]+)&(x)=\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2/%3=1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(\w{3})([^/]+)/(x=\d+)/?$ mconvertar.php?from=$1&to=$2&$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```